# React state array object changes without setState

Tags: reactjs

I have an array which is a state of the React component. This array is a checklist.
var units1 = this.state.units;

when I update units1, this.state.units changes without the this.setState({ units: units1 })

I use `this.setState({ a: 2 });` just to see if the array was updated without `this.setState({ units: units2 });`

this.state.units gets its value from props so if the state changes the props also changes.

```
handleItemChange(e) {
  var units1 = this.state.units.slice();        
  var unit_name = parseInt(e.target.attributes.getNamedItem('data-unit_name').value);
 var new_unit;

  if (!e.target.checked && this.state.units && this.state.units.length > 0) {
  this.state.units.map((unit) => {
    if (unit_name == unit.codpacunidad) {
      if (unit.topics && unit.topics.length > 0) {
        unit.topics.map((topic) => {
          if (topic.codpacunidadtema == e.target.name) {
            new_unit = unit;
            var index = units1.indexOf(unit);
            //units1.splice(index, 1);

            units1 = update(units1, {$splice: [[index, 1]]})

            var topics1 = unit.topics.slice();
            index = topics1.indexOf(topic);
            //topics1.splice(index, 1);

            topics1 = update(topics1, {$splice: [[index, 1]]})

            new_unit.topics = topics1;
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
} else {
  var found_unit = false;
  var name = parseInt(e.target.name);
  var order = parseInt(e.target.attributes.getNamedItem('data-order').value);
  var unit_order = parseInt(e.target.attributes.getNamedItem('data-unit_order').value);

  if (this.state.units && this.state.units.length > 0) {
    this.state.units.map((unit) => {
      if (unit.codpacunidad == unit_name) {
        found_unit = true;
        new_unit = unit;
        var index = units1.indexOf(unit);
        units1.splice(index, 1);

        var new_topic = {
          codpacunidadtema: name,
          orden: order
        };

        var topics2 = new_unit.topics;
        new_unit.topics = update(topics2, { $push: [new_topic]});
      }
    });
  }

  if (found_unit == false) {
    new_unit = {
      codpacunidad: unit_name,
      orden: unit_order,
      topics: [{codpacunidadtema: name, orden: order }]
    };
  }
}

// var units2 = update(units1, { $push: [new_unit]});
// this.setState({ units: units2.sort(function(a, b) {
//     return parseInt(a.orden) - parseInt(b.orden);
//   })
// });

this.setState({ a: 2 }); //just to test if the array gets updated without this.setStaet({ units: units2 })
}
```

Anybody knows why this is happening?

Comment: That's because an array is a reference type, not a value type.  When you change `units1` you're also changing the state. Make a deep copy of the array first.

Comment: how do i make a deep copy of the array? isn't this a copy var units1 = this.state.units.slice()?

Comment: assuming you are using ES6, you could just simply use the ... operator. instead of using  var units1 = this.state.units.slice(); use var units = [...this.state.units], manipulate and once done, use the setState to update the state back.

Comment: This woul work var units1 = this.state.units.map(item=>item) for the units1 variable will be an inmmutable object

Comment: Use lodash.cloneDeep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Alexander van Oostenrijk said to make deep copy of array.

---

Because array are passed by reference which mean memory address of the array is passed not the value of array.

```
  var units1 = this.state.units.slice();
```

Now units1 has the reference address of that array any change made to units1 or this.state.units.slice() will change value of both.As basically they are using address and if one change the value at address then both will read changed value.**Hope you understand**

---

To create deep copy you can create new object like

```
var units1 = Object.assign([],this.state.units)
```

This will create new object with data of this.state.units
**extras** I think you do not need .slice().

Comment: I do need slice() so I can manipulate the array.I did this `var units1 = Object.assign({},this.state.units)`, but when i try to do `units.slice()` I get an error that slice() is not a function

Comment: **Object.assign([],this.state.units)** is perfect for you.I am updating my ans have look again.